# sum id in every group taken one id

Tags: mysql

i got stuck for this query..
i just want to sum result of every id, but every id have many rows..

```
 ID       SUB       Marks    
 1      English     25
 2      English     25
 3      English     25
 4      Maths       10
 5      Maths       10
 6      Maths       10
```

i need the result like this

```
ID         Marks    
 1          35
```

i just take one id every group, then i sum.. how do id finished it?

i try `SUM( distinct..)` but wrong result..

really need your helps guys..

Comment: Use `Group By` to group the result by a specific column and then use `SUM()` to sum up the values. A Google search will help you on this.

Comment: Can you explain your example? Why ID=1 have 35 Marks? I cah only see 25? And post the full query do you have tried.

Comment: Like Jens wrote. The "needed result" is not possible with this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(marks)
from
(
  select distinct sub, marks
  from your_table
) tmp
```

Comment: Result shows only "marks 35". The column "ID" is forgotten